# Logging errors to the ULS with JSOM

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

For SharePoint 2013, is there any way to log to the ULS using the JSOM?

If possible I would like to avoid doing things like writing a custom handler that can be called with ajax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SharePoint provides a web service named SharePoint Diagnostics (`diagnostics.asmx`), this web service enables a client application to submit diagnostic reports directly to the ULS logs, follow  [Writing to the SharePoint Unified Logging Service from JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh803115(v=office.14).aspx) for a more details.

SharePoint JavaScript library (`init.js`) contains the following functions that consume Diagnostics web service:

```
function ULSOnError(msg, url, line) {
    return ULSSendExceptionImpl(msg, url, line, ULSOnError.caller);
}



function ULSSendException(ex) {
    var message = ex.message;

    if (typeof message == "undefined")
        message = ex.toString();
    ULSSendExceptionImpl(message, location.href, 0, ULSSendException.caller);
}
```

**Example**

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
ctx.load(list);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
       //...
   },
   function(sender,args){
       ULS.enable = true; //ensure ULS logging is enabled
       ULSOnError('An error occured while getting list' + args.get_message(), location.href, 0);
   });
```

Comment: If you want to create your own logging method then, there is a webservice that can be found at sharepointserver/_vti_bin/diagnostics.asmx

See the following link for an example on evoking this service. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh803115(v=office.14).aspx